# Android NDK method not found...calling Java from C++

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I want to call a Java method from C++. I've followed other examples I've found, but I keep getting the error:

```
GetMethodID: method not found: Lcom/test/ndk/GL2JNIActivity;.GetFiles:(L/java/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z;)V
```

What am I doing wrong here? I suspect my method signature string is wrong for env->GetMethodID(), but it looks like it's correct from other examples I've seen.

C++:

```
namespace Resource
{
FileInfo *GetFiles(const char *path, const char *mask, bool directory)
{
    JNIEnv *env = Android_JNI_GetEnv();
    jstring jstr1 = env->NewStringUTF(path);
    jstring jstr2 = env->NewStringUTF(mask);

    fileInfos = NULL;

    jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/test/ndk/GL2JNIActivity");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "GetFiles", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z;)V");
    jobject obj = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(clazz, mid);

    return fileInfos;
}
}
```

Java:

```
package com.test.ndk;

import java.io.File;

public class GL2JNIActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

public static void GetFiles(String sentPath, String mask, boolean directory)
{
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+sentPath;
    Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
    File f = new File(path);
    File file[] = f.listFiles();
    Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ file.length);
    for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
    {
        Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + file[i].getName());
        GL2JNILib.AddFileToList(file[i].getName(), file[i].isDirectory());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Holy cow... I can't believe that was it.. haha. Thanks! If you post it as an answer I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace

```
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "GetFiles", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z;)V");
```

by

```
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "GetFiles", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V");
```

because last parameter is a boolean that is not a fully qualified class but a basic type signature so no `;` is needed.